# How to auto place figures on the left in odd pages, and on the right on even pages?

Tags: floats

I'm using `wrapfig`. On every page, there's only one figure (and text). I'd like the placement parameter of wrapfig to be `l` for odd pages, and `r` for even ones, then alternating. Can it be done? If yes, how?

Thanks.

Comment: please see [ifoddpage](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifoddpage) package

Comment: rather than `r` and `l` did you try `i` or `o` options for <i>nside or <o>utside edge?

Comment: Welcome! `wrapfig` has a specialist command for this. Have you looked at the manual? Did you have problems applying it? What's the issue exactly? If you can't get it to work, please provide a minimal working example (MWE) in your question i.e. the code for a complete but minimal document which we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Option [o] is definitely the answer to my issue. I wasn't aware of this option existence, using only the casual '!htblr'. It works all fine now. Thanks cfr and touhami.